# Angular *ngFor set first element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i want to set what the first object of an array would be in my ngFor. This is what i have so far

```
<div *ngFor="let media of allMedia; let first = first; let last = last" 
  [ngClass]="{ first: first, last: last }" >
   <div *ngIf="media.type==='A'">SOME CODE</div>
   <div *ngIf="media.type==='V'" class="header-unit **first**" >SOME CODE</div>
   <div *ngIf="media.type==='B'">SOME CODE</div>
</div>
```

Type='v' is not displayed first. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the value of allMedia ?

Comment: Could you please put your basic code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fp3pmj , its eaiser to debug there

Comment: you forgot the single quotes in the ngClass`[ngClass]="{'first': first, 'last': last }"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the single quotes in the ngClass

```
[ngClass]="{'first': first, 'last': last }"
```

But if you want to show first the media.type=="V" to need transform the array

```
this.allMedia.sort((a,b)=>a.type=='V' && b.type!='V'?-1:
                       a.type!='V' && b.type=='V'?1:0
               )
```

Comment: I tried the quotes Elseo doesn't work. Where should i put this? this.allMedia.sort((a,b)=>a.type=='V' && b.type!='V'?-1:
                       a.type!='V' && b.type=='V'?1:0
               )

Comment: where you get the value of "allMedia"?, after get it sort it

Comment: ok function looks like this allMediaSet() {
  this.offset = 0;
  this.userData.allMedias(this.offset)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
   if (data.success) {
    this.allMedia = data.mediaFeed;
    this.allMedia.sort((a,b)=>a.type=='V' && b.type!='V'?-1:
                       a.type!='V' && b.type=='V'?1:0
               )
   }
  });
 }

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in it's own `*ngIf` directive. Try the following

```html
<div *ngFor="let media of allMedia; let first=first; let last=last" [ngClass]="{ first: first, last: last }" >
   <div *ngIf="media.type==='A'">SOME CODE</div>
   <ng-container *ngIf="first">
     <div *ngIf="media.type==='V'" class="header-unit" >SOME CODE</div>
   </ng-container>
   <div *ngIf="media.type==='B'">SOME CODE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PardeepJain: That's for the OP to say. The question isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: I want the first result - row to be type='V'. Thats all. I tried Michael it doesnt work